# JiraPs consistently returns id error despite using correct Custom id

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

I'm attempting to create a new Jira issue using the powershell code below and I keep getting the error at the bottom.  I can't seam to find what I'm doing wrong.  This is the Powershell I'm using.

```
$cred = mycredential

set-jiraconfigserver -Server "https://myserver.atlassian.net"
get-jiraissue -Issue "DEV-999" -Credential $cred

Get-JiraIssueCreateMetadata -Project DEV -IssueType Task -Credential $cred | ? {$_.Required -eq $true}

#customfield_10029 = @{self=https://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10231; value=DatabaseQueue; id=10231},
$fields = @{
'components' = (
'Century Distribution Systems, Inc.'
)
'customfield_10029' = (
id=1023
)
}
New-JiraIssue -Project "DEV" -IssueType "Task" -Summary "Test for backup automation" -Description "Test for backup automation" -Reporter "me@here.com" -Labels "Maintenance:Refactoring" -Parent "DEV-998" -Credential $cred -Fields $fields -verbose
```

This is the error returned:

> Invoke-JiraMethod : components customfield_10029
> ---------- ----------------- Specify the value for components in an array Specify a valid 'id' or 'name' for Department At C:\Program
> Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\JiraPS\2.9.0\JiraPS.psm1:3603 char:27
>
> - if ($result = Invoke-JiraMethod @parameter) {
> - 
> - CategoryInfo : InvalidResult: (:) [Invoke-JiraMethod], RuntimeException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidResponse.Status400,Invoke-JiraMethod

I can see from the output of get-jiraissuecreatemetadata  that customfield_10029 is the Department field. and I"m using one of the ids that is returned as an allowed value.

> Id : customfield_10029 Required : True AllowedValues :
> {@{self=https://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10228;
> value=BIOperations; id=10228},
> @{self=https://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10232;
> value=DatabaseRelease; id=10232},
> @{self=https://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10231;
> value=DatabaseQueue; id=10231},
> @{self=https://myserver.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10049;
> value=DataWarehouse; id=10049}...} Operations : set HasDefaultValue :
> False Name : Department Schema : @{type=option;
> custom=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:select;
> customId=10029} key : customfield_10029

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax you're using here: `$fields = @{...;'customfield_10029' = (id=1023)}` is incorrect, and `1023` is _not_ in the list of allowed values.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - It would be helpful if you could identify what is wrong with the syntax.  The id should have 10231.  that was a typo.  sorry.

Comment: Looks like you'll want `$fields = @{'components' = @('Century Distribution Systems, Inc.');'customfield_10029' = @{id=1023}}`